# Tables: Make the column in a certain row wider, without the entire table column widening

Tags: php, html, css

I have created the following table to display database results:

echo "";
        echo " ID First Name Last Name Company Name Telephone Alt/ Telephone   Address   Town  Postcode       ";

```
    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table 
    for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
    {
            // make sure that PHP doesn't try to show results that don't exist
            if ($i == $total_results) { break; }
            // echo out the contents of each row into a table
            echo "<tr class='main'>";
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'id') . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'First_Name') . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Surname') . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Company_Name') . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Telephone') . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Alt_Telephone') . '</td>';
            echo '<td> <div style="width: 200px">' .  nl2br(mysql_result($result, $i,'line_1')) . '</div></td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'town') . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'postcode') . '</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'id') . '"><img src="img\Edit.jpg" title="Edit"/></a></td>';
            echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'id') . '"><img src="img\delete.jpg" Title="Delete"/></ /></a></td>';
            echo '<td><a href="archive.php?id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'id') . '"><img src="img\Archive.jpg" Title="Archive"/></ /></a></td>';
            echo '<td><a href="NewJob.php?id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'id') . '"><img src="img\job.jpg" Title="New Job"/></ /></a></td>';
            echo "</tr>"; 
            if (isset($_SESSION['showNotes'])){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td><div ">' .  nl2br(mysql_result($result, $i, 'notes')) . '</div></td>';
            echo "</tr>"; 
            }
    }
    // close table>
    echo "</table>";
```

The if statement at the bottom runs true when a button is pressed (Show Notes) when this is pressed the table displays all of the customer details in a row, then the notes associated with that customer in the row below. the next row is the next customer details followed by their notes..ect.

The table displays like :

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|ID  |  First Name | Surname  | Company Name  |  Tel  | ect |
|                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|Notes|                                                     |
|     |                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

However I want the notes column to to be larger and go about half way across to the tel column, rather than only the ID column, I tried to increase the size of the notes column but it also increased the size of ID rather than going below First name or Surname.

I tried using a div tag like this:

```
echo '<td><div style="width: 200px ">' .  nl2br(mysql_result($result, $i, 'notes')) . '</div></td>';
```

Is there a way I can increase the size of just the notes field?

Comment: That's not how you express tabular data.  Are "notes" an "id"?  If not, why are they in the same column?  Don't pick your markup because you think it looks pretty, pick it because it is semantically appropriate for the information you are presenting.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, A customer in my database has all of the fields including notes in a single row. However when I display the data on my page I need the notes to appear as a new row beneath the other data, and be able to toggle the notes display between show/hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'colspan'

```
<td colspan="3">...</td>
```

You should also think about refactoring your mysql statements out of the file.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried putting the width directly on the TD?

```
<td style="width:200px"> PHP here </td>
```